# Getting error on Post Build in visual studio: the command xcopy exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I converted a project from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2013. On build, I get the following error:
Error   1   The command "xcopy "D:\Projects\Plugins\ConfigurationUtility\trunk\Common - Copy\bin\Release\Common.dll" "D:\Projects\Plugins\ConfigurationUtility\trunk\Common - Copy\bin\Release\" /T /E /Y
copy  "D:\Projects\Plugins\ConfigurationUtility\trunk\Common - Copy\bin\Release\Common.dll" "D:\Projects\Plugins\ConfigurationUtility\trunk\Common - Copy\bin\Release\Common.dll"" exited with code 1.

Comment: Post the content of the Output window.

Comment: Got the solution.The project I was building was under another solution.On building that solution, My error got resolved.